# 'QObject' object has no attribute 'host'

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

When I run the code at [github](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/qml/referenceexamples/binding.py).It shows AttributeError: 'QObject' object has no attribute 'host'.But the author has use decorator to set shis property.I'd like to know how to correct the code to make it work.Thanks!

```
@pyqtProperty(Person, notify=hostChanged)
def host(self):
    return self._host

@host.setter
def host(self, host):
    if self._host != host:
        self._host = host
        self.hostChanged.emit()
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, it works fine with me. I have PyQt5 and Python2.7.

Comment: @tmoreau oh,thank you! I'm at python3.4,Where should I change the code to suit python3.4?

Comment: @tmoreau how to install pyqt5 for python2.7.There are only binary version for python3.4 in riverbank.

Comment: I'm using anaconda, and my only option was to install PyQt5 for Python2.7

Comment: @peter. This is almost certainly due to a bug in pyqt/sip. What *specific* versions are you using? I can reproduce the error using pyqt-5.4.2/sip-4.16.8, but not with pyqt-5.3.2/sip-4.16.4.

Comment: @tmoreau. What versions of pyqt/sip are you using?

Comment: For me, downgrading to pyqt-5.4.1 fixes the problem. If you want to get it fixed properly, I suggest you report it on the [pyqt mailing  list](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt).

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you so much! I'm in sip -4.16.8 and pyqt-5.4.2,so I may need to downgrade.